# Get nth row from JSON array generated by YQL

Tags: arrays, json, yql

I'm using YQL to get and display data from a Google spreadsheet, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/weCve/1/

I'd like to display results from a composite YQL query of multiple queries, and show the results in separate unordered lists.

My composite query is [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=%20SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20yql.query.multi%20WHERE%20queries=%22select%20%2a%20from%20csv%20where%20url=%27https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjghxVM6EpuXdDlVcVpNMUR3RXFNSVl1Y2VjckRqOUE&output=csv%27%20and%20columns=%27title,topic,source,format,link%27%20and%20source=%27one%27;%0Aselect%20%2a%20from%20csv%20where%20url=%27https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjghxVM6EpuXdDlVcVpNMUR3RXFNSVl1Y2VjckRqOUE&output=csv%27%20and%20columns=%27title,topic,source,format,link%27%20and%20source=%27two%27;%0Aselect%20%2a%20from%20csv%20where%20url=%27https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjghxVM6EpuXdDlVcVpNMUR3RXFNSVl1Y2VjckRqOUE&output=csv%27%20and%20columns=%27title,topic,source,format,link%27%20and%20source=%27three%27%22).
and a fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/svh2r/1/

My question is, what do I have to do to this line in order to get it to take a certain row?

```
$.each(data.query.results.results.row, function (i, item) {
```

I thought it would be

```
data.query.results.results.row[1]
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.query.results.results` is an array containing each of the result sets from the separate queries. You can access them individually via `data.query.results.results[n]` where `n` is `0`, `1` or `2` (corresponding with your three queries).

To loop over the results from the second query (offset `1` in the results array) you could do:

```
$.each(data.query.results.results[1].row, function (i, item) { … });
```

It may (or might not) be useful to use two `$.each` loops to loop over all of the rows from all of the results.

```
$.each(data.query.results.results, function (i, results) {
    $.each(results.row, function (i, item) {
         // do something
    });
});
```

Here is an adaptation of your example code, altered to build three lists — http://jsfiddle.net/XfBsj/